# Coupon code system schema design advice

Tags: php, mysql

I'm pretty new to php and mysql and I'm trying to put together a database that will contain customer details, assign these customers to groups, then assign promotions with unique codes to the customers on a group basis.

I've put together a simple schema https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgeCR.jpg would anyone be kind enough to give me some feedback, it seems pretty simple but maybe I'm missing some things those with more experience may pick up on.

Am I right in thinking those tables containing relationships with others are junction tables and are created this way:

```
CREATE TABLE customerPromotions (
    customer_id int(11) REFERENCES customers (customer_id),
    promotion_id int(11) REFERENCES promotions (promotion_id),
    customerPromotions_code_code varchar(12) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (customer_id, group_id)
)
```

Any advice would be great, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

```
CREATE TABLE customerPromotions (
    customer_id int(11) REFERENCES customers (customer_id),
    promotion_id int(11) REFERENCES promotions (promotion_id),
    customerPromotions_code_code varchar(12) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (customer_id, promotion_id)
)
```